# Intellij custom plugin not working it says manifest missing or unable to recognize main class

Tags: intellij-plugin

I have created jar file for Intellij custom plugin and while trying to check it by running it like
java -jar  it says no main manifest attribute,  or some time says not able to recognize main class.
Looking for solution to create intellij custom plugin jar

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not how you should create and build plugin.

Please follow the [Creating Your First Plugin](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) guide in the official IntelliJ Platform SDK DevGuide for more details.